# How do I deploy a new version of a lambda from `dotnet lambda deploy-serverless`

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm deploying a .NET Core Web API project into Amazon Lambda using this tutorial:
[Creating .NET Core AWS Lambda Projects without Visual Studio](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/creating-net-core-aws-lambda-projects-without-visual-studio/)

I have successfully executed the command stack and got the sample Web API app running in Lambda behind an API Gateway:

1. `dotnet new lambda.AspNetCoreWebAPI`
2. `dotnet restore`
3. `dotnet build`
4. `dotnet lambda deploy-serverless -sn stackname -sb bucketname --profile-location ./credentials`

So far so good, and I can get to the app via the `execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com` address and it works.

However, I want to take advantage of the lambda features around versioning so that every time I deploy, it creates a new deployment and allows me to have the API Gateway stages pointing at differing versions of the lambda.

However there is only one version, `$latest`, which always points to the last deployment.

How can I make it have an incrementing version number with the deployments instead of it always just overwriting the `$latest`?

Comment: Is it this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41452274/how-to-create-a-new-version-of-a-lambda-function-using-cloudformation