# Does Updating Description in AWS::Lambda::Version Trigger New Version Creation in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

My use  case:

- I am using CloudFormation to deploy a Lambda function.
- I aim to automate the publishing of a new Lambda version with every code change.
- I prefer not to use AutoPublishAlias since it is available only in SAM
- I also want to avoid renaming the version resource (like changing UnicornStockBrokerFunctionVersion1 to UnicornStockBrokerFunctionVersion$incrementedNumberOfVersion).
- I am aware of combing AWS CLI and CI/CD and it can help me with it, however I want to practice in this case with Cloudformation only.

If I update the description in `UnicornStockBrokerFunctionVersion1` from `Description: v1` to `Description: v2 $timestamp $whatChanged`, will this trigger the publishing of a new Lambda function version in CloudFormation? After changing a description I deploy stack to apply changes in aws. I then pass alias to other aws services which use this lambda

Example code from AWS DOCS github:

```
  UnicornStockBrokerFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref FunctionSourceCodeBucketName
        S3Key: !Ref FunctionSourceCodeKey
      Handler: org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker::handleRequest
      MemorySize: 2048
      Role: !GetAtt 'UnicornStockBrokerFunctionRole.Arn'
      Runtime: java11
      Timeout: 200
      Environment:
        Variables:
          TABLE_NAME: !Ref 'TransactionsTable'
          BUCKET_NAME: !Ref 'ValidationFilesS3Bucket'
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      SnapStart:
        ApplyOn: PublishedVersions
  UnicornStockBrokerFunctionVersion1:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Version
    Description: v1 
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref 'UnicornStockBrokerFunction'
  UnicornStockBrokerFunctionAliasSnapStart:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
    Properties:
      Name: SnapStart
      FunctionName: !Ref 'UnicornStockBrokerFunction'
      FunctionVersion: !GetAtt 'UnicornStockBrokerFunctionVersion1.Version'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62290398/4800344